# Duplicate Message On IOT Edge Hub Send To Cloud

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I get a duplicate message on Cloud, the duplicate message has not come regularly  but it comes any time where I check on my module it sends only one message to the IoT edge hub every 60 seconds, I also check with cloud receive time also I share my excel sheet with sending message time and cloud receive time
[image: Screenshot of an Excel sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible as IoT Hub implements at least once delivery of messages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#sending-cloud-to-device-messages-from-iot-hub

"IoT Hub implements at least once delivery guarantees for both device-to-cloud and cloud-to-device messaging."

If you need to de-dup your messages, you'll have to do some post hub processing and can use services like Azure Stream Analytics to help process the messages.

Comment: My Module send data to edghub but some time i get duplicate message on the cloud and when i deep into problem then i found that edge hub send duplicate message because in time of re-authenticaion to cloud then he edgehub believe that the message are not conform to send so he send second time that i believe